# Why no fadeout?

Tags: jquery

I know I must be missing a semicolon or something simple, but the following code is to fade out a paragraph, which is does, fade in a div called newtext and a button styled with btn2, which it does.  However, when I click the button, the div newtext is supposed to fade out but doesn't.  Any idea what's wrong in the code?  Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   setTimeout(function(){

       $("p").fadeOut();
       $("#newtext").fadeIn();

   $("btn2").click(function(){
       $("#newtext").fadeOut()
       });


   },2000);


});
```

Comment: Why do you have the handler inside timeout?

Comment: Stephen please remember to click/accept one of the answers if it solved your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a class or ID selector here:

```
$("btn2")
```

Your selector should be `$("#btn2")` or `$(".btn2")`, if it is resp. a `ID` or a `class` in that element.

You might also want to move the click event attacher to outside your setTimeout. Like that it will only attach after 2 seconds. (maybe it is the behaviour you want).

Comment: Yes, that did it  -  I didn't have the dot before btn2.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

This code: `$("btn2")` implies that you have an html element like so: `<btn2>...</btn2>`

Perhaps you meant to select a class or id?

For example: `$(".btn2")` for a class or `$("#btn2")` for an id.